# Configuration with @Controller, InternalResourceViewResolver and ModelAndView in Spring MVC doesn't work

Tags: spring-mvc, request-mapping

I'm new to Spring MVC. I know there are a lot of similar questions like this but I already tried most of them for several hours and still facing the issue that 404 error shows up when I request *`http://localhost:8080/SpringRESTFulExample/`* from browser. But there's no any exception in console. 
Here is my code,

RootConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "springrestful_example")
public class RootConfig {

}
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "springrestful_example")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

WebInitializer.java

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(){
        ModelAndView modelandView = new ModelAndView("index");
        return modelandView;
    }
    .
    .
}
```

index.jsp is under **/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp**

[image]

**Dependencies** I use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

That's all I got. Correct me if my code is being wrong. I will be happy if i see Hello World text written in index.jsp body.

Answer (score 0):

What package are your Config classes in? Are they in basePackages you specify? Try not specifying the basePackages in the Component scan annotation.

Comment: Config classes are in springrestful_example.config package.